# Linq to SQL Expression Properties That are Translatable to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a LINQ to SQL class, we'll call it `Test`, and I want to be able to access properties with LINQ queries but I get the famed "No Supported Translation to SQL" runtime error. I'm interested in the conceptual problem. Here is my simplified class:

```
public class Test
{ 
  public int ID {get; set;} // Stored in Database
  public int NonForeignKeyValue {get; set;} // Stored in Database
}
```

Here is sort of an example of what I'm trying to accomplish, but I don't want the overhead of always explicitly writing the join in LINQ:

```
var db = (new DataContext()).GetTable<Test>();
var q = (from t in db.GetTable<Test>()
         join o in db.GetTable<OtherTable>() on o.ID equals t.ID
         where t.OtherStuff
         select t)
```

I'd like to be able to add a property to `Test` that tells me if there are any rows in `OtherTable` that could be joined with `Test`:

```
  public bool IsInOtherTable
  {
    get
    {
       return (new DataContext())
              .GetTable<OtherTabke>()
              .Any(x => x.NonForeignKeyValue == this.NonForeignKeyValue));
    }
  }
```

Ultimately this is what I want my code to look like, but it errors.  I basically want to return all entries that contain some database computed value:

```
using (DataContext db =  new DataContext())
{
   var q = db.GetTable<Test>()
             .Where(x => x.IsInOtherTable && x.OtherStuff); //Error
}
```

I'm basically trying to save myself from writing this code every single time I want to check if Test has certain information in another table. I'm not that interested in the exact problem I described, I'm more interested in how to conceptually add the join part to the SQL and still use LINQ. I'm guessing I use Linq.Expression, but I really don't know and I'm not aware of how to do it.

As an aside, I could just write the actual SQL, as its not that complicated, but I'd like to know how to get around this and still use LINQ.

Edit: I tried this property, but I get the same error.  Its more complicated that just changing the return type to Expression...

```
public System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Article3, bool>> Exists
{
    get
    {
       using (DataContext db =  new DataContext())
       {
         return i => db.GetTable<OtherTable>()
                       .Any(x => x.NonForeignKeyValue == i.NonForeignKeyValue));
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: for starters all queries you want to use together must use the same data context

Comment: do nested using(...) blocks collapse into just one using(...) block? How does that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I think you may be overestimating "the overhead of always explicitly writing the join in LINQ". It's an extra line of code which has the advantage of being relatively self-documenting as to just what you are doing (always a nice thing), and any other approach is going to be turned first into SQL and then into a query plan that will be at least as expensive to execute, possibly more expensive (SQLServer is good a joins!)

Still, there are two alternatives I can thinkof.

One is to have an [EntityRef](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348960.aspx) property on the class that defines this relationship with the other table. You can then test if it is null in your query (or `EntitySet` if it's on the other side of a one-to-many relationship).

The other is to define a SQL function that returns a `bit` result indicating whether an id refers to a row that does or doesn't relate to the other table.

Then define a protected method on your DataContext-derived class that matches the signature in C# terms, and has a [Function attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.functionattribute.aspx) mapping it to that SQL function. (Since this isn't something that you can give a sensible non-db-using version of in the C# version, you can implement the C# function by calling [ExecuteMethodCall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb493883.aspx)).

Then you can use that method instead of the join.

Still, this is likely less self-explanatory in the code and at risk of being less efficient than just keeping the join.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm gonna try and go the EntityRef route.  My goal is to abstract away as much of the complexity as possible, as I'm using a highly normalized schema.  I'm basically trying to achieve functionality, then if (more like when) there are performance issues, I can address them.  This will probably fall into the, needs-to-be-addressed later pile.

Answer (score 1):

Each time the linq generator is to translate a code into a query, it has to process an expression tree.

In your examples, you are not passing around expression but rather - properties, delegates, i.e. stuff which the expression visitor is unable to "step into".

In general, try to rethink your conditions so that instead of `bool` you have `Expression<T, bool>` etc.

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2008/02/linq-to-object-vs-linq-to-sql-and.html

Comment: Your link has some info about Expression<> but it doesn't address the situation where you want to go to the DB again for more information...